# How to fuzzy match a short bit pattern in a long one?

Tags: algorithm, string-matching, fingerprint

I encounter a problem when try to match a short bit pattern in a long one: I have one long bit pattern, e.g. 6k bits, stored in a char array, also a short one, say 150 bits, stored in a char array, too. Now I want to check whether the short bit pattern is in the long bit pattern. While there is no need for short bit pattern to match some part of long bit pattern exactly, I will define a threshold, if the bit-error-rate under it, I will take the two pattern match.

Given the misalignment problem, I can't come up with an elegant solution. One way I can find out is convert the bit pattern into char pattern, i.e. convert bit 1 to '1', 0 to '0' and apply some string matching algorithm. But I'm afraid it may cost memory 7-8 times more burden my system. Someone around me recommend the [Rabin Fingerprint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_fingerprint), however it seems not designed for this kind of problem.

Hope you can give me a hand.

Thanks and best Regards.

Comment: Those patterns are far too small to be a burden on anything.

Comment: @Potatoswatter So you mean I can convert bit to byte? Thanks, and I'll try it if no other choices.

Comment: Do you have a working program yet? If not, the first priority is to test a first draft. Working on optimization before that is a waste of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation you're looking for is *population count* or the closely related *hamming distance*.

Rather than implement lots of bitwise arithmetic by hand, try the [Gnu Multi-Precision Library](http://gmplib.org/), which includes [several bit-string functions](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Logic-and-Bit-Fiddling.html#Integer-Logic-and-Bit-Fiddling).

- Use `mpz_tdiv_q_2exp` to right-shift the long pattern one bit at a time,
- `mpz_tdiv_r_2exp` to extract the last 150 bits, and
- `mpz_hamdist` to find the number of bits flipped between the extracted bits and the short pattern.

Should be plenty fast, and fast to write as well!

As an initial optimization, I would suggest shifting the 150-bit pattern by one-bit increments up to 7 bits, so you have 8 patterns to match against, from 150 up to 157 bits. Then, rather than shift the long pattern one bit at a time (which is slow and likely dominates the runtime), shift 8 bits at a time. Be sure to clear the bits you do not wish to compare.

Comment: An Xnor (negate XOR) could be quicker than computing the Hamming distance and the results seems appropriate for the case

Comment: @belisarius: See the last sentence of the first paragraph of the question. That's pretty much the definition of Hamming distance. Note that Hamming distance is simply equal to the population count of the XOR, hence my "closely related" comment.

Comment: Don't mind. I was thinking of a convolution between the lists using the  Xnor function. If you replace the zeroes by -1, the position in the resulting list holding the maximum value signals the better match.

Comment: @beli: If you use XOR then you can look for the position with the minimum value… and that's the same as my algorithm.

Comment: That is the reason why I have not posted an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets call short bit sequence `S` and long bit sequence `L`.
The algorithm I have in mind is as following:

```
1- XOR S with size(S) rightmost bits of L. Say this is R
2- AND R with R-1 until zero, count how many times, if less than threshold 
   pattern is found
3- Shift right L and go to 1 if size(L) >= size(S)
```

This should take `O(size(L)*size(S))` time in the worst case. But since the number of 1s is way smaller than `size(S)` in each iteration, in practice it should be efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your response at first. I don't quite understand the 2nd step, should I XOR R with (R-1) or (S-1)? Could you please explain more?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! you have to and them! 111 ^ 110 = 110 -- 110 ^ 101 = 100 -- 100 ^ 011 = 000 (3 steps = number of 1s in 111)

Comment: +1 @Pirooz I see. So you want to count how many 1's in the XOR'ed bit pattern, right? Then what about the the shift operation? Should I left shift one bit at a time? If so, I think it's not a trivial work given the underlying data structure is a char array.

Comment: I'm not sure why you keep them in char arrays instead of STL bitsets. You can perform all the bitwise operators easily and efficiently using them. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions with moving the short bit pattern along the longer one have complexity O(N*M) (N - size of short segment, M - size of long segment).

If sizes will grow, you may consider this as a problem of finding shift maximizing (or exceeding threshold of) correlation between two signals and speed it up with Fast Fourier Transform. This may give something like O(N*logN) if I don't mistake.